# Can we check the OpenGL ES version in the build.gradle file?

Tags: android, opengl-es, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle

Is it possible to check the Android device OpenGL ES version in the `build.gradle` file?

Comment: For what purpose? Presumably, you're building your application to run on more than once device, which might have a different GLES version than you have on your device.

Comment: I have implemented Mapbox Sdk in my application. In GLES 2.0 version map's polyline is not rendering on. So I'm trying to check the GLES version at build.gradle.